# How to use Powershell's Uninstall-Package to uninstall *a* specific package from *a* specific csproject

Tags: powershell, package, nuget

So I'm trying to automate some workflow and I'm running into issues with uninstalling/reinstalling a specific package on a specific csproject. I know this is possible with Package-Manager, but how would I achieve this within a powershell script? Here's what my script looks like so far:

```
# delete package folder from local feed
Remove-Item 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\<packageFolder>' -Recurse
# delete past package
Remove-Item '.\<package>.nupkg'
# pack new package
nuget pack '<nuspecPath>.nuspec' -NoDefaultExcludes
# push package to local feed
nuget add '.\<package>.nupkg' -Source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages'
**# Everything below this is not currently working #**
# Remove project's outdated package
Uninstall-Package -Name '<packageName>' -Project '<pathToProject>' -Force
# Install new package to project
Install-Package -Name '<packageName>' -Project '<pathToProject>' -Source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages' -Force
```

So, apparently -Project or -ProjectName are not recognized atrributes when using Uninstall-Package in powershell.. So, how do I specify powershell to uninstall *a* specific package on *a* specific csproject? Any help or insights would be much appreciated!

I tried the above code and kept getting complaints about -ProjectName attribute. I thought that this command would uninstall a nuget package from a specific project and then reinstall a new version of that package to the project.

Comment: Powershell's `Install-Package` doesn't know anything about .NET projects. NuGet's `Install-Package` is only available in Visual Studio's Package Manager Console, not in PowerShell more generally.

Answer (score 0):

*The following answer is valid for .NET (Core) SDK-style projects, but does not work for "classic" .NET Framework projects (see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74879137/how-to-use-powershells-uninstall-package-to-uninstall-a-specific-package-from/74882399#comment132190194_74882399)):*

You may use the [`dotnet` CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/) to manage your projects and solutions.

- Run the following command to list all packages:

  `dotnet list <PATH-TO-PROJECT> package`
- Run the following command to remove a package from the project:

  `dotnet remove <PATH-TO-PROJECT> package <PACKAGE-NAME>`

See [Install and manage NuGet packages with the dotnet CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-dotnet-cli) for more information.

Comment: The question used nuget.exe to pack a project, which only supports packages.config, not PackageReference. The `dotnet` CLI only supports PackageReference (and generally only SDK style projects, not non-SDK style .NET Framework projects). Therefore, there's a reasonable chance this won't work for the person who asked the question, unless they migrate to SDK style projects first.

Comment: @zivkan oops, I didn't grasp this part. I've updated my post.